# FloatingPoint extension - init with other FloatingPoint type

Tags: swift, generics, type-conversion

I need to write an initializer for any `FloatingPoint` value, which can take other type of `FloatingPoint`, and convert it to `Self`. Is this possible in `swift`? I tried something like this:

```
init<FloatingPointType: FloatingPoint>(_ value: FloatingPointType) {
    guard let sameValue = value as? Self else {
        // Pass throu double to get best precision
        self.init(Double(value))
        return
    }
    self = sameValue // The same type
}
```

But this just creates infinite loop. The problem is with creating new self, there is no initializer that takes any other `FloatingPoint`. I think this might be impossible, but maybe there is some way to achieve this.

Comment: You mean you want to cast any Float, Double, and Float80 to Float?

Comment: I need a function or initializer which will allow me to convert Any FloatingPoint like Float, Double, etc to any other FloatingPoint type. And I need this to be generic. So for example I could do: let a = Double(3); let b = Float(a)

Comment: "*to get best precision*" -> Float80. Double is on 64 only. Float is on 32.

Comment: `let a = Double(3); let b = Float(a)` is already possible!

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Looks like you are having a hard time  extending `FloatingPoint` protocol trying to return a `FloatingPoint` object. You can't. You need to return `Self` which can be any type that conforms to `FloatingPoint` protocol like `Double`, `Float`, `Float80`

Comment: this might help. Note that I am extending BinaryInteger but the approach it is the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/52156694/2303865 `var result: Self = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Such initializers already exist in the standard library:

```
let a: Double = Double(3.625)

//From Double to Float and Float80
let b: Float = Float(a)
let c: Float80 = Float80(a)

//From Float to Double and Float80
let d: Double = Double(b)
let e: Float80 = Float80(b)

//From Float80 to Double and Float
let f: Double = Double(c)
let g: Float = Float(c)
```

You can find it right [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/cffe3869a678c62a5d9369fe90a07905cd1d6f07/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPoint.swift.gyb):

```
public init<Source : BinaryFloatingPoint>(_ value: Source) {
    self = Self._convert(from: value).value
}
```